# Visual Studio SSDT how do i run/execute a table that i created? It is a .sql file but not showing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016-localdb

I have used SSDT back in 2014, but I have forgotten most of it AND it seems a lot different now in **with VS 2017** etc..

1. I see both `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` and I see `(localdb)\ProjectsV13` - based on what I read. I assume I should use `MSSQLLOCALDB` (I want create a database project and create my schema with SQL Server Object Explorer, then import the database into a VS database project)
2. I cannot seem to execute the table that I created (I can open up SSMS and create it, but that defeats the purpose of this sort of)
3. Also I want to then send /run on another database server dacpac/bacpac but seems like so many videos are outdated from 2014 using SQL Server Express etc..

Example of simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tablexddd]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Update

So here is the actual table I was trying to publish

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Session_Tracker] (
[Id]          INT            NOT NULL,
[SessionId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[TimerStart]  DATETIME       NULL,
[TimerEnd]    DATETIME       NULL,
[SessionNote] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Tracker_Session] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the stuff you are reading being out of date; how this works is substantially unchanged since 2012 or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a schema compare between the project and the target database. You can find it in `Tools > SQL Server > New schema comparison...` menu.

If all you want is to deploy a single table, complete redeployment sounds like an overkill, while schema comparison looks optimal.

DACPAC is also an option, you can build your database project and the .dacpac file will be created in the /bin/(BuildConfiguration) folder, usually it's `/bin/Debug`. I don't think much has changed in this way of deployment.

Comment: I just tried to publish before reading your answer and I got message  `An error occurred while the batch was being executed.`

Comment: (94,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: I will normally want to have many updates and thus deploy i suppose with a dacpac.  Where is a good up to data online resource (video or blog)  example of how to do this?   thx

Comment: For what it's worth, my blog is older, but should still work: https://schottsql.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/all-ssdt-articles/.   "Localdb" is for debugging purposes - usually populated on a build action unless you change the build target in the project properties.  You should publish the DB to your local instance or an actual instance if you have a choice.  Need more info about why the constraint/index couldn't be created to troubleshoot that particular error.

Comment: Personally I don't use DACPAC deployment because of its many limitations, primarily due to its inability to apply any kind of custom post-deployment processing. Usually I generate a change script from schema comparison and run it with SSMS on the hosting, first against prod backup and then against the prod itself. Any errors that occur during deployment are clearly visible, along with the lines that caused them.